# Auto-completion for \newcommand in TexStudio

Tags: macros, texstudio, auto-completion

I created a new command like this:

```
\newcommand{\longref}[1]{{\ref{#1} (\nameref{#1})}}
```

it works as expected - it prints the chapter number and it's name. Great.

Now I'm using Texstudio, and it always showed me a list of available labels when I was typing in a `\ref`-command. With my own command, it doesn't do that anymore.

Is there any way I get auto-completion with my own command?

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late for OP, but for the record:

To let TeXstudio know what type of fields your command contains, you have to tell it in a `.cwl` file, which is used for auto-completion.

Their default location is `%appdata%\texstudio\completion\` or `.config/texstudio/completion/`.

For your own commands, you can create a file called something like `mycmds.cwl` in the `user` folder there and write the line

```
\longref{label%ref}#r
```

After restarting TeXstudio, the completion should work the way you want it to:

[image]

See also my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585485/163512).

Answer (score 1):

I use TexStudio and it is my favorite editor. I have not particularly tried what you are trying to do here, but here is what I have observed in the latest version of TexStudio. When you load a file in TexStudio, it tries to detect which the parent file is (specially if there are multiple files included in the document, for example, using `subfiles` package). What TexStudio does is that it also loads the resources within those files which you can access. For example, if you load `\usepackage{biblatex}` and the bibliography file `\bibliography{ref.bib}` in the preamble, you will get autocompletion suggestions of the references which are in the `ref.bib` file. So, if you start typing `\textcite{` you will see a list of suggestions (most likely sorted alphabetically) from which you can choose the reference. I am guessing this is the feature you are looking for.

If that is the case, then I do not think custom commands will get the autocompletion feature based on how TexStudio works (at least from what I have seen). I could be wrong since this is just my observation but this is probably it. Hope that helps you understand your situation.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I think I understand. I thought there would be kind of hacky way to declare the type of expected input...